# Is ruby going to get confused if I use variable and @variable in the same method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is ruby going to get confused if I use **variable** and **@variable** in the same method? If not, how about using **variable** and **@variable** in two different action methods but still in the same controller?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No to both questions. Local variables and instance variables will not conflict with each other.

That said, for readability reasons, I would suggest changing one of them.

Answer (score 1):

`variable` and `@variable` are two different variable names so it's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

No you can do it without being worried as they are different. They are two different name so you can do use them both. As for two different action methods you can also do it as they are never loaded together at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

No. The instance variable `@foo` and the local variable `foo` are entirely separate things. Whether it's good style to use both is very debatable, though.

Comment: Isn't it the opposite? if there is a method `foo=` and you in your code will use `foo = "x"` then you have a local variable `foo` with the value of "x", and hasn't used the method `foo=`?